# is it possible for a node to extend/inherit jcr content node (properties and child nodes)

Tags: aem

I need to add a new menu item to siteadmin under `create->menu` of `/libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin`. Now, one way to do that might be to make a complete copy under `apps/<my-app>/wcm/core/content/siteadmin` which works fine. But, I would like to NOT do a deep/complete copy of siteadmin instead have my `app/<my-app>/wcm/core/content/customsiteadmin` extend the lib's siteadmin and be able to add the additional node that i require.

Can somebody tell me what node type/properties that I require on my customsiteadmin node to achieve the same?

PS: I have tried using `sling:resourceSuperType=/libs/wcm/core/content/siteadmin` to the `customsideadmin` node which doesn't work. I guess the `sling:resourceSuperType` is only for overriding script resolution? but the node that I'm trying to override is a like a content node

Answer (score 0):

You can overlay individual files in `/apps` to override functionality of the files in `/libs`. The Adobe documentation has an example for [foundation components](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developing_guidelines_bestpractices.html#Customizing%20Components%20and%20Other%20Elements), but this works for other CQ/AEM functionality as well. Even though the documentation instructs you to copy the entire component, you just need to have the modified file(s) under `/apps`.